# Docker Desktop Kubernetes auth on local machine

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

Is it possible to have docker desktop issue a service token for the host machine so that one can use kubernetes auth method for code running inside an IDE to authenticate with apps running inside a local kubernetes? The instance of kubernetes I am using is by docker desktop for Mac.

Use case: I have deployed vault locally to my docker desktop kubernetes and have configured it to authenticate by kubernetes service tokens. This works fine for apps I deploy to the same kubernetes cluster because they automatically get a service token in their container which they send over to vault for authentication. However, this becomes challenging while I am developing code in my IDE since I am running my app from inside my IDE and to kubernetes cluster, they don't exist. As a result I can't authenticate to vault since I don't have a service token.

I understand this might not be a usual use case and eventually can not be supported. I have tried to spawn up a linux container for the sole purpose of sharing its service account with my local machine to no avail.

Comment: lol, how do I do that?

Comment: twas just a joke my friend. Your question is very complicated. Any chance for a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I added more description. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can make a ServiceAccount and just manually copy the JWT out of the Secret it creates for you. That JWT can be used to access the API from anywhere, no special magic.

Comment: That's definitely an option. I am currently looking for something that doesn't add extra steps to dev machine setup and keeps my code the same on both dev machine and inside kubernetes. If I do this, on my dev machine I will work off a "hardcoded" token and on kubernetes I will get it from /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token.

Comment: I don't know if you're going to be able to make that as automatic as you might hope. Another option is to use another authentication provider in Vault specifically for non-Kubernetes components.

Comment: Right now the closest I am getting is by deploying an alpine image which reads the service token and writes it to a bound volume so that it's accessible from my IDE. It's a dirty trick but that's the closest I can get so far...